# Generating random magic squares

Tags: r, matrix, user-defined-functions, magic-square

I am wondering how to create a matrix with random natural numbers but with the sum of every column equal to sum of every row and diagonal sum also.

I mean that you create a function that by choosing dimension and sum of the rows, columns and diagonals gives you a square matrix as described above but with different numbers on each row and column.

Does anybody know how to make this happen?

I want to create a function on my own without any packages to fully understand the program.

Comment: If the sum of each column is the sum of each row then a lot of numbers depend on others and can't be random

Comment: Are you talking about a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)? Check out the wikipedia article for tips on construction.

Comment: `magic::magic(4)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a package called `magic`:

```
library(magic)
magic(4)
```

output looks like this:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
# [1,]    1   12    8   13 
# [2,]   15    6   10    3 
# [3,]   14    7   11    2 
# [4,]    4    9    5   16
```

You cannot decide what is the sum for the matrix. It is going to be:

[image]**.**

**Where "*n*" is the dimension of the matrix.**

But you can multiply it by a number (preferably an integer).

**Useful Link: *[What is Magic Square?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)***

## How to look into a function?

If you want to figure out how `magic` function works, you can use this and dig into it step-by-step;

```
>functionBody(magic)

# { 
#     if (length(n) > 1) { 
#         return(sapply(n, match.fun(sys.call()[[1]]))) 
#     } 
#     n <- round(n) 
#     if (n == 2) { 
#         stop("Normal magic squares of order 2 do not exist") 
#     } 
#     if (n%%2 == 1) { 
#         return(as.standard(magic.2np1(floor(n/2)))) 
#     } 
#     if (n%%4 == 0) { 
#         return(as.standard(magic.4n(round(n/4)))) 
#     } 
#     if (n%%4 == 2) { 
#         return(as.standard(magic.4np2(round((n - 2)/4)))) 
#     } 
#     stop("This cannot happen") 
# }
```

You need to look into other functions that appears above to fully comprehend the process.